# Google Fit data synchronization issue

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-fit

I tested the google Fit app in different phone, one is lenovo and sony with the same account. So I get different set of data's in each of the mobile because each mobile in different location. But both mobile data are not synchronized, each of them showing only different set of datas.

[image]
[image]
Am Trying to get the google Fit data using nodejs. For a day I got different values in two mobiles. Here what data I need to fetch and show, either from a mobile or from two mobile values.

while fetching the data using dataset, I am getting different value from the two mobiles. How to identify which value I need to add for that day step_count.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related.

Comment: Where  should I post this, I am unable to get synchronized data from the API's and found this inconsistency in the app and am also unable to attach these image on google fit feedback. Please suggest, am struck on this..

Comment: If it's about you having trouble with the APIs when coding yourself it should be on topic. Your question didn't mention that part at all though :) Please add what you're trying to do - code wise - and what problems you're encountering to the question. I don't know just about anything about Google Fit myself, but someone else might.

Comment: Ok, I have added some points relevant to my issue.